# Regular Expression and escape sequences

Tags: python, regex

I have a file which contains the list of regular expressions to look for in db.

one such pattern is `(/|\)cmd\.com$`. But when i use it with re module, it throws up the below error.  If i use the re pattern as  `(/|\\\\)cmd\.com$`,it works.

So, the question is when i read from a file in to variable for EX: a, how do i convert it to a reg pattern with four backward slashes so that it starts working with python re module.

Also, how do we escape such escape sequences when reg pattern is assigned to a variable EX: "a" below.

Any help on this is appreciated.

```
import re
a='(/|\)cmd\.com$'
re.compile(a)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/re.py", line 245, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Thx,
Santhosh

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Answer (score 3):

First note that your original regex is invalid. It should be `(/|\\)cmd\.com$`. If such a string is coming from a database (or any other source other than a string literal in your code), then no additional manipulation needs to be done before the regex engine sees it -- the slashes are correct.

Full details and explanation:

Backslashes are special in that they escape other characters and give them different meanings.

```
a = '(/|\)cmd\.com$'
```

In this regular expression, the `)` is special, indicating the end of a grouping expression; the backslash escapes it to make it interpreted as a literal `)` instead, which is not what you want (and why you get the error about mismatched parentheses).

You need to escape the backslash to make it be interpreted as a literal `\`; this can be done using yet another backslash:

```
a = '(/|\\)cmd\.com$'
```

However even this will not work, since in Python there are two levels of processing going on (and thus two levels of escaping are needed): First, the string literal is evaluated, and the backslashes are interpreted specially (string-wise, where e.g. `\.` is not meaningful, and so evaluates to `\.` -- however `\\` evaluates to `\`). Then, when the regex engine gets the string, it interprets any literal backslashes in *that* object specially (regex-wise, e.g. `\.` makes the `.` literal instead of "any character"). So you end up with:

```
a = '(/|\\\\)cmd\\.com$'    # Escaped version of (/|\\)cmd\.com$ which is what regex engine will see
```

Because this problem is so common, Python has a way of writing strings such that the backslash is *not* treated specially in the string-processing stage: ["raw" string literals](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals):

```
a = r'(/|\\)cmd\.com$'    # backslashes here will be interpreted as literal \ characters
```

The regex engine will still interpret the backslashes in the string specially (a raw string is just a way of writing the literal; it still results in a plain `str` object).

Comment: I am aware of this, but may be i need to put the question straight. 
Let us say i have a file of regular expressions. So,

import re
for items in open(file,'r').readlines():
    re.compile(r items)

How do i put r items joined together in re.compile statement above. Hope it is clear.

Comment: @Santhosh: Not quite sure what you are asking for. Do you want to join a list of regular expressions into one big one? If so, `string = open(file, 'r').read().replace('\n', '')` should do the trick. Then, you could say `re.compile(string)`

Answer (score 1):

In your example above, you need to make the regex pattern a Python "raw" string, like so:

```
  re.compile(r'put the pattern here')
```

If you post your code I might be able to help with your question about loading patterns from a file.

Comment: I am aware of this, but may be i need to put the question straight. 
Let us say i have a file of regular expressions. So,

import re
for items in open(file,'r').readlines():
    re.compile(r items)

How do i put r items joined together in re.compile statement above. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Nope, re.compile() is meant to be called on the *pattern*.  So:
`
  import re
  pattern = re.compile(r'your pattern here')
  for items in open(file).readlines():
    match = pattern.match(items)
    if match:
      pass # Do something
`